# Post to external URL and show page

Tags: jsf, post

There is a requirement in the webapp I am developing (not changeable unfortunately ) that states that I have to send via post certain parameters to a servlet from a JSF managed bean. That servlet then forwards to a page where it shows some of the parameters sent via POST in a form for the client to see.

That servlet is part of an external application, thus I cannot use RequestDispatche.

I have tried Apache Http client but i get to a point that the post URL responds with the content of the page (i can actually see the HTML in my logs), what i would like to do is forward to the page not receive it as answer in my code.

If this makes no sense let me know :).

EDIT: 
what i need to do is:
JSF BEAN->POST data to an external servlet -> Follow servlet redirect/forward to an external page

One way I'm thinking of doing this is forwarding to an internal facelets or JSP page that builds a hidden form with all required parameters and automatically submits it to the post Servlet

Answer (score 0):

So after trying to find other ways to do it, I have decided to go this way:
Create an internal page, with a hidden form that will be automatically committed with a small javascript.
Get all required data in the bean, navigate to page, fill hidden fields with the required info, post to external servlet.

I should also say that a better way to do this kind of interaction would be:

- Post data to servlet (for example using apache http client)
- manage the servlet response (for example 200 OK)
- navigate via GET (using a redirect) to the servlet by passing some id as a
  get parameter through which the data can be shown in the page

This would require the servlet to accept POST and get requests, and also to have a way to get the data sent via post when it's called via get. This was not the case for us.